# Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'

Tags: php, htaccess

I am moving a WordPress site from a shared hosting package to a VPS at 1and1 hosting. They have PHP ver. 5.1.6 but PHP5 support is there. I added the following 2 lines on the top of .htaccess file to use that:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

.htaccess is in `mydomain.com/httpdocs`

But is shows me this error: `Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'` and php file appears as simple text file. Please visit [this](http://bit.ly/tgWOnx)

Cannot understand the reason. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the lines and give it a try ;)

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```